# How to convert SD-BD Video to DVD Video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, dvd, bluray

this is my first post here:

I have several homemade, simple Bluray PAL SD Video iso files without menus. They are converted from PAL DV to mpeg2video and PCM audio to .mts and with tsMuxer to Bluray.iso. Duration playtime on each BD-R DL 50 GB disc is about 3.0 - 3.5 hours.

Instead of making DVD video options also from scratch, I wonder if it easier/possible to convert the SD-BD M2TS files to compliant target DVD video?

I would be thankful for suggestions on using ffmpeg procedures for this.

Inspecting a typical SD-BD-video.m2ts by mounting the iso:

```
mount SD-BD_DV58_09+DV59+DV60.iso /mnt2
mount: /mnt2: WARNING: source write-protected, mounted read-only.

ls -lh /mnt2/BDMV/STREAM
total 36G
-r--r--r-- 1 nobody nobody 36G Apr 16 18:58 00000.m2ts

ffprobe -hide_banner /mnt2/BDMV/STREAM/00000.m2ts
Input #0, mpegts, from '/mnt2/BDMV/STREAM/00000.m2ts':
  Duration: 03:00:12.12, start: 4200.000000, bitrate: 28013 kb/s
  Program 1
  Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(tv, bottom first), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 25000000/0/0 buffer size: 28000256 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: pcm_bluray (HDMV / 0x564D4448), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
```

Thanks
Terje J. Hanssen